# Fulltext index is not creating

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to craete Fulltext index in my table column but it give me error.

My query are as follow:

```
create table products
(
p_id int primary key,
p_name varchar(50),
)

insert into products values(1,'Sugar')
insert into products values(2,'Tea')
insert into products values(3,'Flour')
insert into products values(5,'Soap')

create index pname on products(p_name)
select * from products

create fulltext catalog product as default

create fulltext index on products(p_name) key index pname on product
```

it give this Error:

> Msg 7653, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 'pname' is not a valid index to
>   enforce a full-text search key. A full-text search key must be a
>   unique, non-nullable, single-column index which is not offline, is not
>   defined on a non-deterministic or imprecise nonpersisted computed
>   column, does not have a filter, and has maximum size of 900 bytes.
>   Choose another index for the full-text key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should give a name to your PRIMARY KEY and use it as a KEY INDEX in the last statement.

```
create table products
(
p_id int CONSTRAINT [PK_products] PRIMARY KEY,
p_name varchar(50),
)

....
create fulltext index on products(p_name) key index PK_products on product
```

[KEY INDEX index_name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx)

**Is the name of the unique key index on table_name. The KEY INDEX must be a unique, single-key, non-nullable column. Select the smallest unique key index for the full-text unique key. For the best performance, we recommend an integer data type for the full-text key.**